# Play audio online in ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net

i need to play audio online in asp.net website

My requirement is

users will be able to browser the audio file using file upload control and two button will be displayed 'Play' and 'Stop'.

site should have the capability to play audio file in any format.

Please share any links or code to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into these links. They may help.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1303198.aspx

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/5014-Play-Audio-File-Wav.aspx

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/22231-Play-audio-files-asp-net.aspx

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/PlaySoundsInASPX09032006083212AM/PlaySoundsInASPX.aspx

Comment: Yes, go through http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/MP3PlayerControl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not most appropriate but worth a thought
you can try embedding a silverlight element..
In silverlight you can import the audio file to project
and then can just drag and drop "media element" set source.
drag and drop buttons play and pause..
play : mediasource.play();
pause : mediasource.pause();

voila done.. Its easy to do all this in sileverlight..

Comment: Its plain asp.net application, Don't want to use silverlight.